# Make Excel File editable in asp.net core 2 web view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm working on this project which involves uploading an excel file that I got working however I want to be able to edit that said file in web view in asp.net core 2.

I have tried looking around to do this however i seem to be getting nowhere.

```c#
public ActionResult OnPostImport()
        {
            IFormFile file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            string folderName = "Upload";
            string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string newPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath, folderName);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string sFileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
                ISheet sheet;
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, file.FileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    if (sFileExtension == ".xls")
                    {
                        HSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read the Excel 97-2000 formats  
                        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        XSSFWorkbook hssfwb = new XSSFWorkbook(stream); //This will read 2007 Excel format  
                        sheet = hssfwb.GetSheetAt(0); //get first sheet from workbook   
                    }
                    IRow headerRow = sheet.GetRow(0); //Get Header Row
                    int cellCount = headerRow.LastCellNum;
                    sb.Append("<table class='table'><tr>");
                    for (int j = 0; j < cellCount; j++)
                    {
                        NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICell cell = headerRow.GetCell(j);
                        if (cell == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cell.ToString())) continue;
                        sb.Append("<th>" + cell.ToString() + "</th>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                    sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
                    for (int i = (sheet.FirstRowNum + 1); i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++) //Read Excel File
                    {
                        IRow row = sheet.GetRow(i);
                        if (row == null) continue;
                        if (row.Cells.All(d => d.CellType == CellType.Blank)) continue;
                        for (int j = row.FirstCellNum; j < cellCount; j++)
                        {
                            if (row.GetCell(j) != null)
                                sb.Append("<td>" + row.GetCell(j).ToString() + "</td>");
                        }
                        sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</table>");
                }
            }
            return this.Content(sb.ToString());
        }
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnUpload').on('click', function () {
        var fileExtension = ['xls', 'xlsx', '.csv'];
        var filename = $('#fUpload').val();
        if (filename.length == 0) {
            alert("Please select a file.");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var extension = filename.replace(/^.*\./, '');
            if ($.inArray(extension, fileExtension) == -1) {
                alert("Please select only excel files.");
                return false;
            }
        }
        var fdata = new FormData();
        var fileUpload = $("#fUpload").get(0);
        var files = fileUpload.files;
        fdata.append(files[0].name, files[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Employee/OnPostImport",
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
            },
            data: fdata,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.length == 0)
                    alert('Some error occured while uploading');
                else {
                    $('#dvData').html(response);
                }
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $('#dvData').html(e.responseText);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

The code uploads the file into the wwwroot, which is cool, but I want to be able to edit that file when viewing it on the net.

Comment: You should probably map it to a model, map the model to input fields and then write it on post to a new file.  Preserving the field types may be an issue... and also unicode quirks.  OR use a browser extension?: https://www.offidocs.com/index.php/productivity-chrome-firefox-extensions/excel-xls-editor-web-browser-extension

Comment: @pcalkins, Is there any example of what you are talking about as I roughly know what you're saying, but getting my head around it is another thing altogether.

Comment: a lot of the implementation would depend on requirements...    Are the incoming files standardized?  Do you want to store in a database?  What is the basic problem you are trying to solve?